# Joined Table Confusion - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I'm a little befuddled on how to create a joined table in ROR.

Let's say there are 2 tables:

- User
- Book

In order to create a joined table `user_book`, my initial impression was that you did this:

```
rails g migration user_book
```

But I've been told that to create an actual joined table, I generate an actual model:

```
rails g model user_book
```

Is that correct?

And if the second one is correct, then once I've created it, I open it and add both the `book_id`, and `user_id` to the migrated file, and then run `rake db:migrate` command. Is this correct?

EDIT:

Just wanted to added that

User model would have this: `has_many :books, through: :user_book`

Book model would have this: `has_many :users, through: :user_book`

Comment: IMHO, there are two ways: you either create a model without a table, that matches many to many or whatever you have, or create an actual table (in case you have some extra attributes which integrity you should guarantee on the db level).So, in both ways you should create a model, but only in the second case you need migration.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "joined table." A join is something that happens when you query a table, not something that happens when you create the table. I recommend reading the [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) Rails Guide, which will tell you both how to create associations between models and the basics of migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `has_many through:`, you need a [table to handle that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).  As well as a model object to represent that table.

How you go about creating it (`rails g model` or `rails g migration`) doesn't ultimately matter.  All those commands do is create either a model AND a migration file, or just a migration file.  Personally, I would do the `rails g model`, since you need both.

You'd just add a `user_books` table with 2 IDs, `user_id` and `book_id`.

Migration would look something like this:

```
class CreateUserBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_books do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.references :book, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Models would look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_books
  has_many :books, through: :user_books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_books
  has_many :users, through: :user_books
end

class UserBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end
```